# How to send R code to sublime REPL in sublime text3

Tags: r, sublimetext3

I'd like to write R code in Sublime Text3, now I can send the R code in sublime to R GUI. I wonder if there's a way to send the R code to REPL window, so it would be more convenient and save lots of time.

Sublime Text 3, Version 3.2, Build 3200

R, Version  3.5.3 (2019-03-11) -- "Great Truth"

For Sublime Text 3, I have installed sublimeREPL,R-Box, SendCode packages. And it works to send the code to R GUI.

I want working and getting the results only in Sublime Text3 with a side-by-side window, not need to check it in the R GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. 
While in Sublime Text 3, type Ctrl+Shift+P -> "SendCode: Choose Program". In the list that appeared, pick "SublimeREPL". 
It now sends my R code from the script tab to the REPL tab when I do Ctrl+Enter, for instance.